# friedmanTestBMR using one classifier with multitasks - mlr

Tags: r, benchmarking, mlr

I have run a benchmark experiment with several tasks, containing different subsets of the data, with one classifier (random forest from the package `ranger`).
Now I would like to compare on significance between different models using the post hoc Friedman-Nemenyi test with the `mlr` function `friedmanTestBMR()`. This, however, does not work because `friedmanTestBMR()` needs at least 2 classifiers. Does it have any statistical reason? 
Using `posthoc.friedman.nemenyi.test()` from the R-package `PMCMR` (which `friedmanTestBMR()` uses) works fine.

Comment: Good point; this should probably be supported. mlr is currently in maintenance-only mode with most development effort focused on mlr3, but if you want to have a go at changing this and open a pull request (https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/wiki/pr-guidelines) you're more than welcome (and we'll help).

Comment: `friedmanTestBMR` test for differences between learners and not for differences between tasks.

Comment: Thank's for your answers. 

@Lars Kotthoff: the function has an explicite if statement to end this function if n.learner < 2 therefore I assume there is a (statistical) reason for it.
`if (n.learners < 2) { stop("Benchmark results for at least two learners are required") } n.tasks = length(bmr$results) if (n.tasks < 2) { stop("Benchmark results for at least two tasks are required") }`

@jakob-r can you give further information why this function can be just applied to compare between learners and not between tasks (only)?

What kind of function/method could I use?